# Salesforce LWC dynamic rendering

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am working on a simple Switcher LWC which has 2 buttons. For simplicity, lets call them Car and Truck button. The logic is very simple, when user clicks on Car button, it should show carLWC and clicking on Truck should user truckLWC. The logic is working only on page load, but selecting Truck button and then select Car button again, it is not rendering the carLWC.

For testing, I included cardTitle LWC and that is showing correct value based on which button is clicked.

What may be wrong?

== JS ==

```
export default class SwitcherComponent extends LightningElement {
    @track isCarSelected = false;
    @track isTruckSelected = false;
    @api recordId;
    cardTitle;

    // Wire to get the record data
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId' })
    wiredRecord ({ error, data }) {
        if(data) {
            this.recordId = data.fields.Id.value;
        }
    }

    get carButtonClass() {
        return this.isCarSelected ? 'slds-button slds-button_success' : 'slds-button slds-button_neutral';
    }
    
    get truckButtonClass() {
        return this.isTruckSelected ? 'slds-button slds-button_success' : 'slds-button slds-button_neutral';
    }

    handleCarClick() {
        this.isCarSelected = true;
        this.isTruckSelected = false;
        this.cardTitle = 'Search Cars';
    }
    
    handleTruckClick() {
        this.isCarSelected = false;
        this.isTruckSelected = true;
        this.cardTitle = 'Search Trucks';
    }
}
```

== HTML ==

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Search Component Switcher">
        <div class="toggle-buttons">
            <button
                class={carButtonClass}
                onclick={handleCarClick}>
                Car
            </button>
            <button
                class={truckButtonClass}
                onclick={handleTruckClick}>
                Truck
            </button>
        </div>
        
        <div class="search-container">
            <template if:true={isCarSelected}>
                <c-search-car
                    card-title={cardTitle}
                    record-id={recordId}>
                </c-search-car>
                <c-title-component
                    card-title={cardTitle}
                    card-icon=utility:truck_config>
                </c-title-component>
            </template>
            <template if:true={isTruckSelected}>
                <c-title-component
                    card-title={cardTitle}
                    card-icon=utility:truck_config>
                </c-title-component>
            </template>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```